# VSTS - System.InvalidOperationException: Can't determine the folder to restore NuGet packages. Specify either -PackagesDirectory or -SolutionDirectory

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore

I have a Visual Studio 2017 solution that includes 2 projects. One project uses .NET 4.7.1. The other project uses .NET Core. I'm interested in automating the build of my .NET 4.7.1 project in VSTS. However, at this time, my build fails with an error that says:

```
The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot determine the packages folder to restore NuGet packages. Please specify either -PackagesDirectory or -SolutionDirectory.
   at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.GetPackagesFolder(PackageRestoreInputs packageRestoreInputs)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.<PerformNuGetV2RestoreAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.<ExecuteCommandAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot determine the packages folder to restore NuGet packages. Please specify either -PackagesDirectory or -SolutionDirectory.
   at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.GetPackagesFolder(PackageRestoreInputs packageRestoreInputs)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.<PerformNuGetV2RestoreAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.<ExecuteCommandAsync>d__30.MoveNext()<---)
Packages failed to restore
```

This failure occurs during the first task in my VSTS build pipeline. That task is defined with the following properties:

```
Command: restore
Path to solution, packages.config, or project.json: MyNet471Project/MyNet471Project.csproj
Feeds to use: Feed(s) I select here - <My Private NuGet repo>
Disable local cache is not checked
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this issue. What am I missing?

Update
Notably, I've deleted the "packages" directory at the solution level and the "bin" directory on my local machine. When I rebuild the solution in Visual Studio, Visual Studio automatically gets the packages and successfully builds.

However, if I run `nuget restore MyNet471Project/MyNet471Project.csproj` from the command line, I get a similar error to the one I see in VSTS. The error in the command line says:

```
Cannot determine the packages folder to restore NuGet packages. Please specify either -PackagesDirectory or -SolutionDirectory.
```

What is Visual Studio running to automatically restore the packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a value to the "Destination directory" property and it worked!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, if possible, you could accept it as answer. So it could help other community members. Have a nice day:)

Comment: Hello, which value did you specify for "destination directory" property ?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it looks like there are not `packages.config` or `project.json` file where `MyNet471Project.csproj` located.

In the field `Path to solution, packages.config, or project.json:` try to give the path to `packages.config` or `project.json` file itself and not to `MyNet471Project.csproj`, or give a path to the solution where the `packages.config` exists in the same folder.

Comment: I tried to reference the `packages.config` file explicitly in the "Path to solution, packages.config, or project.json" field. Unfortunately, that did not work and yielded the same error.